# Issues setting images as a div background

Tags: html, css

I  want to make two images part of a background div, one at the top and the other at the bottom but the bottom image keeps extending my div height and width.

This image is what I am trying to recreate:

[image]

I have both background patterns saved and I want to position one at the top left and the other at the bottom right without altering my div's width or height

I've tried using positions and even margins but it keeps extending my div

```css
.body {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #1799A7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
}

.bg-top {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -400px;
  margin-left: -400px;
}

.bg-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">

  <div class="bg-top">
    <img src="images/bg-pattern-top.svg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="bg-bottom">
    <img src="images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using background-image?

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was really helpful I made more research on background-image and It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://codepen.io/marceloag/details/DbqYwy

An almost identical template is solved in this codepen.

This example also includes JavaScript, which you can omit:

```
$(document).ready(
  function iniciar(){
  $('.follow').on("click", function(){
    $('.follow').css('background-color','#34CF7A');
    $('.follow').html('<div class="icon-ok"></div> Following');
  }); 
  }

);
```